# Stop VS 2010 from Auto Creating Braces After else keyword

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm using VS 2010, and I'm getting constantly annoyed when I type "else" and then it auto returns line and adds braces. Something like:

```
else
{

}
```

I cannot imagine I'm the only one who often puts one-liners after the else and prefers no braces. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but always using braces is (I've found) a good habit to get into/standard to use, as it avoids any possible future bug where a one-line else is turned into a multi-line else incorrectly.

Comment: Point taken, I'm just strangely bothered by those methods that are just a few lines where I want to return something quick and easy and VS wants me to put brackets where they're uneccesary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally figured out what the hell is doing this. I have ReSharper installed on this machine, and apparently the "else" keyword is a ReSharper autocomplete keyword. So even after I turned off the braces completion, ReSharper was still kicking in and adding them. Rage. In order to stop this, you have to turn off the ReSharper autocomplete.

Answer (score 12):

I also found this behavior very annoying.

My first attempt involved opening the Templates Explorer (ReSharper / Templates Explorer...), selecting C#, then unchecking "else". This did get rid of the braces. Unfortunately, hitting enter after "else" now just added a space! I was having to hit enter twice. Not quite what I was hoping for.

But if you double-click on the else template it opens up an editor where you can specify what happens. I found that simply removing the braces gave me the functionality I desired - hitting enter after an else was now putting me on a new line, tabbed over under the else - without braces.

To recap, to fix this you need to open Resharper's Templates Explorer, select the C# scope, then double-click on the else template and remove the braces. Your template "snippet" should look like this (just two lines):

```
else
  $END$
```

This works in Resharper 6.1 and Visual Studio 2008. I have no idea about other versions of the software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to disable brace auto-complete for specific keywords. If you go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting
```

you'll find the various formatting options. It's possible to disable auto complete in general or affect indentation and such, but I don't see any way to disable brace auto complete for specific keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)? You can turn it off in Tools, Options, "Productivity Power Tools", "Automatic Brace Completion". (I know I do)

Comment: Hey, this wasn't it, but I did DL the extension. Very slick.