# ReSharper Auto-Inserts braces on "else"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

This question is similar to this one:
[Stop VS 2010 from Auto Creating Braces After else keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664884/stop-vs-2010-from-auto-creating-braces-after-else-keyword/6749233#6749233) 
But I can't comment on there and it's not really solved.

Basically, ReSharper inserts { } on pressing enter after an "else".

I tried everything and even changed the ReSharper option "Braces in 'if-else' statement" to "Remove braces".
Doesn't do anything.
Disabled both options under "Braces and Parenthesis" in "Editor Behavior" - nothing.

The solution for the question linked above said to disable auto-complete. I haven't found an option to do this.

I'm using VS 2013 and ReSharper 6.0.20141219.

Comment: The question you are referencing has an answer that mentions Reshaper's Templates Explorer (the one with the most up votes).  That fix worked for me.  Did you try that one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop VS 2010 from Auto Creating Braces After else keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664884/stop-vs-2010-from-auto-creating-braces-after-else-keyword)

Comment: @juharr That just worked for me too. Note that when double-clicking the "else" in the template editor, it opens it in a Visual Studio edit window which may be behind the resharper template editor.

Comment: You can install R#6.0 on VS 2013?

Comment: @TyCobb Pretty sure you can't... I suspect a copy/paste issue.

Comment: I don't have the "Template Explorer". Maybe this wasn't installed with ReSharper?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Reharper Templates Explorer (Resharper->Templates Explorer...), select the C# scope and then deselect the 'else' template.

(This was using Resharper 8.2.3 and Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: I don't have the "Template Explorer". Maybe this wasn't installed with ReSharper?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment for [Piers Myers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28516288/308024), so I paste new answer.

The Reharper Templates Explorer can be also found under **Resharper->Tools->Templates Explorer...**

Disabling `else` template works for me (ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3 on VS 2017).